# Concave function first-order conditions

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $g(x)$ be a function defined over the unit interval $[0, 1]$. Suppose that $g (0) = g (1) = 0$, and $g''(x) \le 0$, for any $x \in [0, 1]$.

Show that for any $x \in (0, 1)$, $g'(x) \le \frac{g(x)}{x}$

What I've tried is the mean value theorem, but can't get the right answer.

$g'(c) = \frac{g(x) - g(a)}{x - a}$

$(x-a)g'(c) = g(x) - g(a) \le g(x)$

$g'(c) \le \frac{g(x)}{x - a}$ and $\frac{g(x)}{x - a} \ge \frac{g(x)}{x} $ as $ 1> x > a > 0$ so dividing by $(x - a)$ yields a larger number.

But obviously the inequalities don't quite work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Use the fact that $g(0)=0$ and that $g'$ is decreasing, and consider $\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}$, to get the answer

Comment: I still can't quite get it to pop out. I get there exists c such that f'(c) = g(x)/x but can't see where to go from there?

Comment: $c<x$ and hence $g'(c)\geq g'(x)$ as $g''\leq 0$

Comment: Ah, yes, I'd forgotten c must be less than x. Great, thank you!